# Breeze EntityManager.executeQuery with expand - httpResponse data does not match result data?

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

I'm working on a web app that uses Breeze and Knockout.  I have the following function:

```
function getArticle(id, articleObservable) {
    var query = EntityQuery.from('KbArticles')
        .where("articleId", "==", id)
        .expand("KbArticleType, KbSubject, KbArticleTags");

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        if (articleObservable) {
            articleObservable(data.results[0]);
        }
        log('Retrieved [Article] from remote data source', data.results.length, true);
    }
}
```

A **1 to many** relationship exists between the **KbArticles** entity and the **KbArticleTags** entity.  The goal of this function is to fetch a specific article and the list of tags associated with the article.  The function executes successfully (and I DO get data for the other 2 expanded entities - they are 1 to 1), however, I get an empty array for the **KbArticleTags** in `data.results`.  Interestingly, the tags are populated in `data.httpResponse`:

[image]

[image]

So, it appears that the data is coming over the wire, but it's not making it to the results in the `querySucceeded` function.  I tried to step through the breeze code to determine how the httpResponse is mapped to the result, but got lost fairly quickly (I'm a javascript newb).  Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips for figuring out why the expanded entity doesn't show in the results, but is returned in the httpResponse?  Or am I trying to do something that isn't supported?

Comment: you should examine breeze metadata. make sure your one-to-many relationship is defined correctly and all property names match exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for whatever reason (I probably deleted it one day while testing and didn't add it back), the navigation property (in my Entity Framework diagram) was missing on the **KbArticleTag** entity:

[image]

All I had to do was add that back and everything is working as expected.

[image]